# Datatables placing down arrow too cramped in length box

Tags: datatables

I have some datatables (as in datatables.net) running in PHP within a Laravel 9 framework. Everything works fine but the select length drop down is too small and results in the down arrow impinging on the number as below:

[image]

I have tried to find the css class which appears to be:

```
div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_length select {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

but changing this seems to have no effect - min-width etc. And I did clear all caches!

The rest of it is perfect.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably have some additional style sheets interfering with the default DataTables styling. But without the relevant code, that is just a guess. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried to find an overriding css for this but I cannot and Chrome is giving me no help whatsoever.

Comment: Right. But I am asking for a [mre] not for any specific CSS.

Comment: I think I have found the problem and have come up with a work around. I thoroughly check everything to do with the select statement and placed a dummy one on the same page. The dummy one was fine but the problem continued with the datatables. So I though I would change "All" to "All Records" and it worked. Something is looking for the max length of the labels. If "All Records" is chosen then there is still the problem with the positioning of the arrows, but I can live with that for the moment. I tried adding some space at the end of the label but I can only assume the javascript is trimming.

Comment: I did try various methods with padding "all Records" but it is always trimmed.

Comment: Sorry I should have added that the problem with the arrows only occurs on the "All Records" label if chosen.